# Scrapy response.follow throws error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm following this intro to scrapy : 
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/intro/overview.html

And the code runs well until it needs to jump to the next page, then I get the following error stack :

```
2017-08-09 19:45:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/> (referer: None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/totosh/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/Users/totosh/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/Users/totosh/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/Users/totosh/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/totosh/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/totosh/OneDrive/data analysis and ML/python working directory/scrapy0.py", line 48, in parse
    yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'follow'
```

What causes that ?

Is it because the html is : `<a href="/tag/humor/page/2/">Next <span aria-hidden="true">→</span></a>` and does not have the absolute URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Scrapy are you using? The `follow` method of `Response` objects was added in Scrapy 1.4.0 - see the [Release notes](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html).

Comment: Thanks, I used an earlier version installed through anaconda, which apparently does not provide the latest version, now it works!